# Extract and calculate JSON values in select query

Tags: mysql

I tried Google it, but I couldn't find something :/

I want to extract values from JSON string from `TEXT` field and run a calculation in the query.

For backward compatibility I cannot use the new JSON column type in MySQL.

The JSON is `{"stock1":1,"stock2":1}` in a field called `json_field_total_stock`.

So what I want is "3" because the total stock is 1 + 2 = 3 in stock `json_field_total_stock`.

So my select would look something like this:

```
 SELECT json_field_total_stock
      , order_quantity 
   FROM products 
  WHERE json_field_total_stock = order_quantity;
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write code to extract the numbers from the JSON and add them.

```
WHERE SUBSTR(json_field_total_stock, 
             LOCATE('"stock1":', json_field_total_stock) + 9,
             LOCATE(',', json_field_total_stock) - LOCATE('"stock1":', json_field_total_stock) - 9) +
      SUBSTR(json_field_total_stock, 
             LOCATE('"stock2":', json_field_total_stock) + 9,
             LOCATE('}', json_field_total_stock) - LOCATE('"stock2":', json_field_total_stock) - 9) = order_quantity
```

If you have more than 2 items in the JSON, it gets much more complicated. If the number is unlimited, you'll need to write a stored function that performs a loop to add them all.

It would probably be easier to do this in a client language with a JSON library and the ability to loop over arrays or objects.